# What is the difference between a grounded tip soldering gun and a grounded soldering gun?

Tags: soldering

What if any is the difference between a grounded tip soldering gun and a grounded soldering gun?  My son needs one for school.

Comment: What sort of school will your son attend, what subject, what level, ...? Do you have examples of either soldering irons?

Comment: The school my son goes to won't let them do anything fun.  They have to wear eye protection just to mix powdered drinks like Kool-Aid.  Not kidding.

Answer (score 2):

A grounded soldering iron will have its body set to ground.  Generally if a soldering iron power plug has a third prong (the ground prong) then the soldering iron will be grounded.  This helps prevent shocks because any current leakage will be directed towards ground and not towards you.

A grounded tip soldering iron has its tip set to ground reference i.e it will be set to the ground reference of your power plug - again check for the third prog in the power supply.

If your son is going to work with ICs and other delicate electronics then a grounded tip soldering iron is the one you want.  The grounded tip will ensure that any excess charge will be channeled away instead of into the chip thus preventing ESD (Electro-Static Discharge) damage.

If you just need a soldering iron to solder copper pipes in your bathroom then either kind is fine.

Comment: If you need a soldering iron to solder copper pipes, what you really need is a blowtorch - probably cheaper, and way more fun.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you shouldn't be worried. Every soldering iron (gun in your case) is grounded because of safety precaution if heater or anything in iron goes bad/fuses so that a handler using a iron wouldnt be hurt. Just like any electric appliance handled by human (eg. electric stove)

Second difference on "grounded" iron tip would be if you handling some esd sensitive devs, that in school probably wont do, that you wont damage items you're soldering with tool you use. Beside obvious thermal shock etc.